# Cannot access nested data from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get nested data.comments in this case

[image]

Mission Class:

```
public class Mission implements Serializable {

    private String body;
    private String name;
    private Integer vote;
    private List<Comment> comments;
    private int completedby;
    Mission() {
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public int getCompletedby() {
        return completedby;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Integer getVote() {
        return vote;
    }

    public List<Comment> getComment() {
        return comments;
    }
}
```

Comment class:

```
public class Comment {
    private String body;
    private String username;
    private int vote;

    public Comment(){}

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public int getVote() {
        return vote;
    }
}
```

This is how I retrieve data.I cant access comments body.I can access missions properties by the way.(except comment list its null)

```
mydb.child("missions").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            missionMap.put(childSnapshot.getKey(),childSnapshot.getValue(Mission.class));

        }
        Log.d("working",missionMap.get(missionMap.keySet().toArray()[0]).getBody()); // working 

Log.d("comment",missionMap.get(missionMap.keySet().toArray()[0]).getComment().get(0).getBody()); // not working
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

And the error thrown is.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
> 'java.util.Set java.util.Map.keySet()' on a null object reference

For some reason List is null.Its not filled with comment objects.

**UPDATE**

I found the problem with my code.In my code Comments are coming as a HashMap. I dont really care about comments id.I just want to store them as a List.But they are coming as hashmap.How to retrieve them as a list without their ids ? (ciid for example) So store all comments as comment object inside a list.Thats what i am trying to do.I can convert hashmap values to list easy but maybe there is another way to do that

Comment: What are the exact value that you want to get from the database?

Comment: comments. i want to reach comments body username vote

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ..

```
    mydb.child("missions").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {


                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Mission mission = childSnapshot.getValue(Mission.class);
                    if (mission != null && !mission.getComment().isEmpty()) {
                        for (Comment comment : mission.getComment()) {
                            Log.d("comment", comment.getBody());
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


        }


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is:

> `java.lang.NullPointerException`: Attempt to invoke interface method '`java.util.Set java.util.Map.keySet()`' on a `null` object reference

So you're calling `Map.keySet()` on a non-initialized object.

The only places in the code you shared that do this call look like this:

```
missionMap.keySet()
```

So it seems that you never initialize `missionMap`. The simplest fix is to create the map in your `onDataChange()`:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Map<String, Mission> missionMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        missionMap.put(childSnapshot.getKey(),childSnapshot.getValue(Mission.class));
    }
    Log.d("working",missionMap.get(missionMap.keySet().toArray()[0]).getBody()); // working 
    Log.d("comment",missionMap.get(missionMap.keySet().toArray()[0]).getComment().get(0).getBody()); // not working
}
```

Comment: when i try like this         Log.d("comment",missionMap.get(missionMap.keySet().toArray()[0]).getComment().toString()); // not working
        getComment returns a null

Answer (score 0):

To get those value, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ciidRef = rootRef.child("id").child("missions").child("comments").child("ciid");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String body = dataSnapshot.child("body").getValue(String.class);
        String username = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
        long vote = dataSnapshot.child("vote").getValue(Long.class);
        Log.d("TAG", body + " / " + username + " / " + vote);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ciidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The outut will be:

```
  //blank String
  //blank String
0
```

Comment: I found the problem with my code.In my code Comments are coming as a HashMap. I dont really care about comments id.I just want to store them as a List.But they are coming as hashmap.How to retrieve them as a list without their ids ? (ciid for example) So store all comments as comment object inside a list.Thats what i am trying to do.